# VS Code terminated with exit code: 4294967295

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, ssh, windows-10

I have spent around two days to solve this but got no luck. My Vs Code is working fine but suddenly it starts showing the error `The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe /c (type "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\vscode-linux-multi-line-command-172.16.16.96-566984369.sh" | ssh -T -D 50126 172.16.16.96 bash) & exit /b 0" terminated with exit code: 4294967295.` I don't know what happen.

I am using VS Code on my Window 10 Machine and trying to connect to my office Mac Machine.  Everything is working before last 2 days.

I am using VSCode-Insider and Remote SSh nightly extension.

Further stack trace is

```
[19:29:36.337] remote-ssh-nightly@2020.9.2340
[19:29:36.337] win32 x64
[19:29:36.344] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+172.16.16.96", attempt 1
[19:29:36.345] SSH Resolver called for host: 172.16.16.96
[19:29:36.345] Setting up SSH remote "172.16.16.96"
[19:29:36.604] Using commit id "e790b931385d72cf5669fcefc51cdf65990efa5d" and quality "insider" for server
[19:29:36.614] Install and start server if needed
[19:29:39.671] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[19:29:40.070] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5

[19:29:40.108] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 50126 172.16.16.96 bash
[19:29:40.217] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[19:29:40.810] > 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[19:29:40.810] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[19:29:40.940] > 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
[19:29:44.719] > Password:
[19:29:44.720] Showing password prompt
[19:29:45.861] "install" terminal command done
[19:29:45.862] Install terminal quit with output: Password:
[19:29:45.863] Received install output: Password:
[19:29:45.865] Stopped parsing output early. Remaining text: Password:
[19:29:45.865] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[19:29:45.879] Resolver error: Error: 
    at Function.Create (c:\Users\Dell\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-nightly-2020.9.2340\out\extension.js:1:130564)
    at Object.t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\Dell\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-nightly-2020.9.2340\out\extension.js:1:127671)
    at I (c:\Users\Dell\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-nightly-2020.9.2340\out\extension.js:127:106775)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
    at async c:\Users\Dell\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-nightly-2020.9.2340\out\extension.js:127:104774
    at async Object.t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\Dell\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-nightly-2020.9.2340\out\extension.js:127:109845)
    at async Object.t.resolve (c:\Users\Dell\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-nightly-2020.9.2340\out\extension.js:127:107960)
    at async c:\Users\Dell\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-nightly-2020.9.2340\out\extension.js:127:141955
[19:29:45.886] ------




[19:29:50.235] Password dialog canceled
[19:29:50.236] "install" terminal command canceled
```

Comment: Did you had any success?